# Ethereum Name Service (ENS) is case-sensitive?

Tags: addresses, ens

Are the ENS addresses case-sensitive?

Making different example.eth from ExAmple.ETH?

If I'm going to bid on a name I must pay attention on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to add to the previous answer, I believe ENS implements [RFC5891 section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5891#section-4), which has this to say about case sensitivity:

> Labels MUST be compared using equivalent forms: either both
> A-label forms or both U-label forms.  Because A-labels and
> U-labels can be transformed into each other without loss of
> information, these comparisons are equivalent (however, in
> practice, comparison of U-labels requires first verifying that
> they actually are U-labels and not just Unicode strings).  **A pair
> of A-labels MUST be compared as case-insensitive ASCII (as with
> all comparisons of ASCII DNS labels).**  U-labels MUST be compared
> as-is, without case folding or other intermediate steps.  While
> it is not necessary to validate labels in order to compare them,
> successful comparison does not imply validity.  In many cases,
> not limited to comparison, validation may be important for other
> reasons and SHOULD be performed.

(See comments from [EIP-162](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/162).)

Answer (score 4):

Like DNS, ENS is also **case insensitive**. i.e, the ENS name are lowercase as in DNS.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[EIP-137](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/384ca913cf23673da6922ed2494b1278101560f4/EIPS/eip-137.md) is the spec describing ENS. In short, it says that **it's possible to register an upper-case name, but no correctly functioning resolver will resolve to that name**.

> Are the ENS addresses case-sensitive?
>
> Making different example.eth from ExAmple.ETH?

It depends on what layer you're interacting with:

- If you are using a user-friendly tool, it should handle all this for you. The experience will seem case-insensitive.
- If you are manually crafting transactions for the network, you need to force the name to lower-case first (as well as make other normalizations).

> If I'm going to bid on a name I must pay attention on that?

Probably not, because you should be using friendly tools like MyEtherWallet.

### Source

In the ["Name Syntax" section](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/384ca913cf23673da6922ed2494b1278101560f4/EIPS/eip-137.md#name-syntax) of EIP-137, it says:

> Each label must be a valid normalised label as described in [UTS46](http://unicode.org/reports/tr46/) with the options `transitional=false` and `useSTD3AsciiRules=true`. For Javascript implementations, a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idna-uts46) is available that normalises and checks names.
>
> Note that while upper and lower case letters are allowed in names, the UTS46 normalisation process case-folds labels before hashing them, so two names with different case but identical spelling will produce the same namehash.